# In outliers detection, train test split after or before fit the algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, outliers

I'm implementing an outlier's detection pipeline.

3 escenarios raised when I train the algorithm:

Should I first split the data before fitting my outlier's detection algorithm?

Should I fit only on train?

Should I split and then fit on train and test separately?

For illustrative purpose I'm going to use iris dataset

A similar discussion is stated here in the case of scaling:

[Why do we need to re-use training parameters to transform test data?](https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/scale-training-test.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from warnings import filterwarnings

filterwarnings('ignore')


X,y = load_iris(return_X_y= True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .3, random_state = 123)


# Option 1

Iso_outliers = IsolationForest().fit(X_train)

Iso_outliers_train = Iso_outliers.predict(X_train)

Iso_outliers_test = Iso_outliers.predict(X_test)

# Option 2

Iso_outliers_train = IsolationForest().fit_predict(X_train)

Iso_outliers_test = IsolationForest().fit_predict(X_test)

# Option 3

Iso_outliers_X = IsolationForest().fit_predict(X)
```

1. Which of the 3 above options is the correct one and why?
2. Does it depend on the algorithm to be used or it would apply the same for any outlier's detection algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- The correct one is option 1. The right thing to do is to fit your model on your train data. Because that is the purpose of splitting the data into train and test sets. Train set is the information that you use to build your model and test set is used to test your model, calculate error and accuracy. If you train your model with both test and train data then you have no data to validate your model. This is why option 3 is not correct.
The first statement in option 2 is equivalent to

```
    Iso_outliers = IsolationForest().fit(X_train)
    Iso_outliers_train = Iso_outliers.predict(X_train)
```

So there is nothing wrong with using it. However, in the second statement, you "fit and predict", which means you use test data to build the model again and predict using the model that you build with the test set. So, there is no use of train set.

2-The general practice to build any model in machine learning (It is independent from the algorithm that you want to implement) is:

1. First, use train data to build the model.
2. Then, use test data to validate and evaluate the model.

You can read [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets) for a better understanding of dividing data into train-test-validation sets.

Answer (score -3):

1. **remove the outliers**
2. **split** the data into training data and testing data.
3. **train** the data with **fit** and then test data.

[image: Jupyter notebook snapshot]

Comment: Consider adding the code in the answer itself, rather than uploading it as image.

Comment: Test dataset is the untouched dataset, this includes outlierhandling. The order should be: (1) train-test split (2) handle outliers ONLY on train

Comment: I agree with @Bengi Koseoglu. You cannot modify/spoil test data. It would be like choosing questions for your school test.

Comment: We should not change the test set using the information from the train set. So, this order is not correct.